# How does fixed (one of quad methods of triangulate modifier) define first point and third point?

Tags: python, mesh, modifiers

I want to unify the triangulation methods of my models. I have two initial models with the same mesh but different triangulation methods. I import them into Blender and use the "Planar" option of the Decimate modifier to merge triangles. Then, I apply the Triangulate modifier to triangulate them. However, even when using the same triangulation method - FIXED, I notice that it produces different results. I suspect this is due to differences in how the first and third points are defined. The same issue arises when using other quad-methods. How can I address this?

This is my code:

```
import bpy

def unify_triangulate(input_path, output_path):

    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='MESH')
    bpy.ops.object.delete()


    bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf(filepath=input_path)


    obj = bpy.context.active_object
    obj.modifiers.new(name='Decimate', type='DECIMATE')
    obj.modifiers['Decimate'].decimate_type = 'DISSOLVE'
    obj.modifiers['Decimate'].angle_limit = 0.0872665  # 5 degrees in radians
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier='Decimate')


    # obj.modifiers.new(name='Triangulate', type='TRIANGULATE')
    # obj.modifiers['Triangulate'].quad_method = 'SHORTEST_DIAGONAL'
    # bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier='Triangulate')


    # bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    # bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
    # bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
    # bpy.ops.mesh.quads_convert_to_tris(quad_method='BEAUTY', ngon_method='BEAUTY')


    bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(filepath=output_path, export_format="GLTF_SEPARATE")
```

This is my results:

model 1 initial:

[image: model 1 initial]

model 1 result:

[image: model 1 result]

model 2 initial:

[image: model 2 initial]

model 2 result:

[image: model 2 result]

Comment: "Fixed" is based on the internal order, `mesh.polygons[x].loop_indices[0,1,2,3]`. [Source code](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/9795c432e1cb65bf17e154478252f6d266d79afa/source/blender/bmesh/intern/bmesh_polygon.cc#L996). I'm not sure any of the methods are completely independent of this internal order if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the reason is the differences between the two models' internal order even after using a decimate modifier (planar). But do you know how to unify the internal order?

Comment: I guess you could sort every poly's loop indices by (say) the vertex XYZ in lexicographic order using Python.

Comment: @scurest I don't think this is a good idea, as you want to ensure non-overlapping triangles in n-gons. The lowest vertex could be the first face corner, but even then you run into a problem of a tie-breaker if two vertices of a face are at the exact same $z$ (which will happen often). So just use the lowest vertex index for the first face corner, and from there, count corners in a counter-clockwise direction, by looking from the forward side of the face (from where the face's normal points).

Comment: @scurest Thanks for your answer again. It appears that the desired functionality cannot be achieved using Blender's existing features, is that correct? Do you know how to implement it using Python code? If you could implement it upon my previous code, I would be grateful.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thanks for your answer. The answer looks a little bit hard to understand. Do you know how to implement by codes? Thanks.

Comment: Hi all! I try to use python to sort vertices of each face, but not success. I post the new question in https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/313748/how-to-resort-vertices-order-of-faces