# How to update mesh data?

Tags: python, mesh, bmesh

I want to resort the order of vertices of faces in Blender by python. It looks like the resort function works well. But I think the new data does not update to the mesh successfully. How to modify my codes?

```
selected_faces = [f for f in obj.data.polygons]
i = -1
for face in selected_faces:
    i = i+1

    vertex_indices = face.vertices


    vertices = [obj.data.vertices[i].co for i in vertex_indices]


    new_vertices = sorted(vertices, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1], x[2]))
    new_vertex_indices = [vertex_indices[vertices.index(vertex)] for vertex in new_vertices]

    obj.data.polygons[i].vertices = new_vertex_indices
    bpy.context.active_object.data.polygons[i].vertices = new_vertex_indices


# bpy.ops.mesh.normals_make_consistent(inside=False)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
```